# Can I select multiple audio output devices in javascript

Tags: webrtc, audio-streaming, getusermedia, mediadevices

I am developing a webRTC app that includes two audio players, each of which should output their audio simultaneously to a distinct audio device.

The user would select, e.g., "Internal Speakers" as the output for one stream, and "External Headphones" as the output for the other stream.

I have experience using `getUserMedia()` with webRTC to select sources and outputs for a page:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

However, I can't find an (even experimental) way for a single web page to output separate streams to separate devices.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: You can open different devices from different documents (pages, tabs, windows).

Comment: Thanks, @O.Jones—that's a really good point! That's one good way of solving the problem. My ideal, though, would be doing this within the same document.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. I've never succeeded at getting it to work.